# AVAssetTrack totalSampleDataLength is 0

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, avfoundation

I'm programming an iPhone app which uses an `AVAssetReader` to read samples from an `AVAssetTrack`, I need to allocate some memory which depends on the number of samples in the `AVAssetTrack`, but for some reason `totalSampleDataLength` is returning 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

< warning - guess! >

Perhaps it's something to do with the [AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol - do you have to ask it to load the value for that key before it's populated?

Comment: Well I did try that, by calling: [theTrack loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"totalSampleDataLength"] completionHandler:^(void){NSLog(@"Length is %lld",theTrack.totalSampleDataLength);}]; But it still returned 0.. Maybe the key I'm using is wrong?

Comment: oh :( What do you get if you call `statusOfValueForKey:error:` in your completion block - you should get `AVKeyValueStatusLoaded` - there might have been an error getting the data?

Comment: Okay, sorry for the delay, I tried that and it does return AVKeyValueStatusLoaded. I also noticed that this seems to happen with my own tracks which are mp3s, I converted a few tracks to m4a to test the effect of different bit depth, sample rate, and number of channels, and with these songs I am able to extract information about the avassettrack without problems. Could it be a limit with the file format or something?

Comment: Honestly? No idea! However, if those keys are reporting AVKeyValueStatusLoaded and aren't giving valid information I'd submit a bug to apple :) (http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/)

Comment: Cheers for your help, I'll try that =)